# Why does background service not work from Android 8

Tags: android, flutter, background-service

I'm trying to run a background but it's not working as expected ,when I run setAsForeground everything works fine but when I run setAsBackground and I close the app the service will also stop.
(Android sdk 29)

background_service.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service_android/flutter_background_service_android.dart';

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
        autoStart: true,
        onForeground: onStart,
        onBackground: onIosBackground,
      ),
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
          onStart: onStart,
          isForegroundMode: true ,
          autoStart: true)
      );
}

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
Future<bool> onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  return true;
}

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  if(service is AndroidServiceInstance){
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });
    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) async {
    if(service is AndroidServiceInstance){
      if(await service.isForegroundService()){
        service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(title: "heloo", content: "duyMoiChoi");
      }
    }

    print("background service is runing...");

    service.invoke("update");
  });
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'background_service.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Permission.notification.isDenied.then((value) {
    if(value){
      Permission.notification.request();
    }
  });
  await initializeService();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

```
FlutterBackgroundService().invoke("setAsBackground")
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  flutter_background_service: ^2.4.6
  flutter_background_service_ios: ^2.4.0
  flutter_background_service_android: ^3.0.3
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
```

I tried to find out about it but couldn't find anything, I only know that since Android 8 it has been limited
I need a background service to receive notifications from the server